# How to say grief delayed for good cause?

Tags: popular-refrains

What words, or phrases, are related to grieving having been deferred, but not disparaged, for a worthy reason?

Bonus points for folklore references.

===

I was thinking of something along the lines of, 'Today is a good day to die.' A saying that would affirm the value of the grieving process, while providing kind of a personal narrative framework to put a pin in it for later, because something more pressing, possibly life threatening, needs dealing with at the moment.

Comment: What context do you have in mind?

Comment: In the film Toy Story, Buzz Light-year claims: "This is no time to panic." (Woody responds, "This is the perfect time to panic.")

Comment: I don't think you meant to use the word *disparaged*. Did you mean *dismissed*? Also, I'm not quite clear what even that means in this context. Do you mean don't think about it or deal with it now, but do so later? What's an example of this—and of a worthy reason?

Comment: A word for putting off grief that is heard seldom now is *Subsumed* meaning *put under* or *kept under*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin That's the overt sentiment, but I'm hoping to find something that recognizes the toll of deferring it and carries an implicit promise of a happy future time where healing can occur.

Comment: @Elliot Subsumed is good. It speaks to the emotional process of suppressing the  feelings. That's definitely along the right lines, but I'm looking for something that really puts it in a human context.

Comment: @JasonBassford Both really. My goal is to give the impression that while the grief is set aside for the time being, it's a sacred facet of human life deserving of every respect.